# Receive mail, and resend to another email server with conditions

Tags: python, email, postfix-mta

Without using Postfix, Sendmail, Qmail or Exim, is it possible, in pure Python, to have a server that receives emails, and based on certain conditions (such as the subject), redirects them or not to another email server, i.e. a gmail address?

**Does Python have receiving-only email capability built-in, without third party module, in a similar way that it has `http.server` built-in?**

Comment: The close reason here is slightly misleading. There are not really multiple questions here. We used to have a "too broad" reason which included "lacks effort or demonstration of any research" but the correct close reason now would really be "needs details or clarity". Anyway, please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask;](/help/how-to-ask) perhaps you can still edit this into a form which is acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is [smtpd — SMTP Server](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/smtpd.html).
However, the `smtpd`module is deprecated since Python version 3.6.
The recommended replacement is [aiosmtpd](https://aiosmtpd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is not in the standard library, alas not build in.